# MySQL server very high load

Tags: mysql, database, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I run a website with **~500 real time visitors**, **~50k daily visitors** and **~1,3million total users**. I host my server on **AWS**, where I use several instances of different kind. When I started the website the different instances cost rougly the same. When the website started to gain users the RDS instance (MySQL DB) CPU constantly keept hitting the roof, I had to upgrade it several times, now it have started to take up the main part of the performance and monthly cost (around 95% of (2,8k$/month)). I currently use a database server with 16vCPU and 64GiB of RAM, I also use Multi-AZ Deployment to protect against failures. **I wonder if it is normal for the database to be that expensive, or if I have done something terribly wrong?**

[image: Current settings]

[image]

**Database Info**

At the moment my database have 40 tables with the most of them have 100k rows, some have ~2millions and 1 have 30 millions. 
I have a system the archives rows that are older then 21 days when they are not needed anymore.

**Website Info**

The website mainly use PHP, but also some NodeJS and python.

Most of the functions of the website works like this:

1. Start transaction
2. Insert row
3. Get last inserted id (lastrowid)
4. Do some calculations
5. Updated the inserted row
6. Update the user
7. Commit transaction

I also run around 100bots wich polls from the database with 10-30sec interval, they also inserts/updates the database sometimes.

**Extra**

I have done several things to try to lower the load on the database. Such as enable database cache, use a redis cache for some queries, tried to remove very slow queries, tried to upgrade the storage type to "Provisioned IOPS SSD". But nothing seems to help.

This is the changes I have done to the setting paramters:

[image]

I have though about creating a MySQL cluster of several smaller instances, but I don't know if this would help, and I also don't know if this works good with transactions.

If you need any more information, please ask, any help on this issue is greatly appriciated!

Comment: You said you tried to upgrade to provisioned IOPS, but were you maxing out the IOPS available to you already? Are you still maxing out the available IOPS? You need to look at your "Read Operations per Second" and "Write Operations per Second" and see if they are being limited by the available IOPS.

Comment: Also, I would suggest testing Aurora to see if it performs better for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience, as soon as you ask the question "how can I scale up performance?" you know you have outgrown RDS (edit: I admit my experience that leads me to this opinion may be outdated).

It sounds like your query load is pretty write-heavy. Lots of inserts and updates. You should increase the innodb_log_file_size if you can on your version of RDS. Otherwise you may have to abandon RDS and move to an EC2 instance where you can tune MySQL more easily.

I would also disable the MySQL query cache. On every insert/update, MySQL has to scan the query cache to see if there any results cached that need to be purged. This is a waste of time if you have a write-heavy workload. Increasing your query cache to 2.56GB makes it even worse! Set the cache size to 0 and the cache type to 0.

I have no idea what queries you run, or how well you have optimized them. MySQL's optimizer is limited, so it's frequently the case that you can get huge benefits from redesigning SQL queries. That is, changing the query syntax, as well as adding the right indexes.

You should do a query audit to find out which queries are accounting for your high load. A great free tool to do this is https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html, which can give you a report based on your slow query log. Download the RDS slow query log with the http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/download-db-log-file-portion.html CLI command.

Set your long_query_time=0, let it run for a while to collect information, then change long_query_time back to the value you normally use. It's important to collect all queries in this log, because you might find that 75% of your load is from queries under 2 seconds, but they are run so frequently that it's a burden on the server.

After you know which queries are accounting for the load, you can make some informed strategy about how to address them:

- Query optimization or redesign
- More caching in the application
- Scale out to more instances

Comment: I'm curious why you think they have "outgrown RDS". It seems like all the tuning you suggest can be done while still using RDS.

Comment: My opinion may be outdated. For years RDS could not tune the InnoDB log file size, or offer query logs except for table-based logs. That seems to have changed. But I guess I have a prejudice against a database server I can't log into! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is "you're doing something wrong".  It is very unlikely you have reached an RDS limitation, although you may be hitting limits on some parts of it.

Start by enabling detailed monitoring.  This will give you some OS-level information which should help determine what your limiting factor really is.  Look at your slow query logs and database stats - you may have some queries that are causing problems.

Once you understand the problem - which could be bad queries, I/O limits, or something else - then you can address them.  RDS allows you to create multiple read replicas, so you can move some of your read load to slaves.

You could also move to Aurora, which should give you better I/O performance.  Or use PIOPS (or allocate more disk, which should increase performance).  You are using SSD storage, right?

One other suggestion - if your calculations (step 4 above) takes a significant amount of time, you might want look at breaking it into two or more transactions.

Answer (score 2):

A `query_cache_size` of more than 50M is bad news.  You are writing often -- many times per second per table?  That means the QC needs to be scanned many times/second to purge the entries for the table that changed.  This is a big load on the system when the QC is 2.5GB!

`query_cache_type` should be `DEMAND` if you can justify it being on at all.  And in that case, pepper the `SELECTs` with `SQL_CACHE` and `SQL_NO_CACHE`.

Since you have the slowlog turned on, look at the output with pt-query-digest.  What are the first couple of queries?

Since your typical operation involves writing, I don't see an advantage of using readonly Slaves.

Are the bots running at random times?  Or do they all start at the same time?  (The latter could cause terrible spikes in CPU, etc.)

How are you "archiving" "old" records?  It might be best to use `PARTITIONing` and "transportable tablespaces".  Use `PARTITION BY RANGE` and 21 partitions (plus a couple of extras).

Your typical transaction seems to work with one row.  Can it be modified to work with 10 or 100 all at once?  (More than 100 is probably not cost-effective.)  SQL is much more efficient in doing lots of rows at once versus lots of queries of one row each.  Show us the SQL; we can dig into the details.

It seems strange to insert a new row, then update it, all in one transaction.  Can't you completely compute it before doing the insert?  Hanging onto the inserted_id for so long probably interferes with others doing the same thing.  What is the value of `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode`?

Do the "users" interactive with each other?  If so, in what way?